# check with *ngIf, if there is an array or not (Angular 4)

Tags: arrays, json, angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I'm looping through a json file with *ngFor. While looping through the data, I want to check for every person, if it has no colors array. I do this with *ngIf.

**JSON**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Peter",
    "colors": [
      {
        "color": "blue"
      },
      {
        "color": "yellow"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Maria"
  }
  // has no colors array
]
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let person of persons">
     <div *ngIf=" what comes here?? ">
        <p>{{person.name}} has no colors</p>
     </div>          
</div>
```

How can I check, if a person has no colors array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simply :

```
 <div *ngIf="!person.colors">
     <p>{{person.name}} has no colors</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: If there is no color but an array (`[]`), this won't work.

Comment: I agree, the question asks for the existence of an array, but come on, we both read the sentence in the condition, you should check for it at least ! And thank you for the upvote !

Comment: I'm not talking about fairness, rather about ... Well I don't know the word for that. Completeness ?

Comment: @JeremyThille I've tried the exact same before because I also thought this would be the right solution but it just won't show "person has no colors"

Comment: @trichetriche exhaustiveness?

Comment: @JeremyThille I agree, that's called a hold-up :D I think I have upset the OP when I said "good luck finding your mistake" ... Well, good for you !

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<div *ngFor="let person of persons">
  <div *ngIf="person.colors && person.colors.length">
```

With words, it gives

> If the array exists and has at least one element in it

The opposite would be

```
  <div *ngIf="!person.colors || !person.colors.length">
```

Which you can shorten with an **[Elvis operator](https://www.joshmorony.com/safely-displaying-data-with-the-elvis-operator/)**

```
<div *ngIf="!person.colors?.length">
```

Comment: ya this would work but i have no array, so unfortunately i cant use this. but thanks anyway

Comment: Because **[on my side](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-lhgt6r?file=app/app.component.html)**, it works like a charm @BlueCat

Comment: I'm not getting any error. But it just wont show "Person has no colors". Your code seems correct to me and I would have solved it the same way, but I just can't figure out what might be wrong.

Comment: Then you should post your code, because we're not psychics !

Comment: Well, I dont have much more code than this and I think posting the rest would be a bit unneccessary. But I upvoted your post because it should be correct and I think there might be just a problem with my configuration and not the code.